# White Flash on First Page Load: Can this be "fixed?"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've noticed that on the first load of some of the pages on my site, there's a quick white flash.

It doesn't seem to do this once the page content has been cached, but it's annoying during the first loads.

I tried styling all of the `<html>` tags black, but that doesn't seem to solve the issue. Could it be the scripts on some of my pages? (i.e. maybe analytics)

Is there anything I could do to remedy this problem?

**Update:** The site can be [viewed here](http://www.caseykidd.com). Some pages have Javascript, but others do not, and it seems that's irrelevant, based on the results I've experienced.

Comment: It could be a number of things - what's the URL to your site?

Comment: If I were to guess though, it's probably a resource that blocks momentarily before the document can render. Are all your <script/> tags at the bottom? Will the page render without javascript at all?

Comment: @cirrus: See the update above...

Comment: Might be the full page image being loaded. Seems to happen the first time and then not again (due to caching).

Comment: It seems as though styling the `html` tag black should prevent this though, wouldn't you think?

Comment: Not necessarily. You need to get that in as early as possible, and it's still a network hop away in home.css. You want that hack in before you have loaded any other resources if possible. Having said that, I don't think it will block on a <link/> tag like it will a <script/> tag, but it can't set the html tag black until it's loaded that additional file. So that may be (part) cause of the white flash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, so it looks like this might be related to your script tag in the `<head/>`. Try pushing that down to just before the closing `</body>` tag. The document can't render until that script has completely run.

See [rule 6](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/high-performance-sites-rule-6-move-scripts-bottom-7200.html)

However, one of the other resource you're waiting on sometimes is 'home.css'. That may even be more of a problem. It's a bit of a hack, but you could try setting your background to black before even that css using an inline `<style/>` tag.

Try structuring the page in this order (notice the `<style/>`) tag;

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html { background-color: black; }
</style>
...
<link href="home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
...
</head>

<body>
...
<div id="footer">
    <span class="footer_text">Copyright © 2013 Casey Kidd Music.<br />All Rights Reserved.</span>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
  (function(
      ...
  'pageview');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's possible you may still get a small flicker of white between pages, before the HTML has loaded, but this window would be pretty small now.

Comment: Or `<html style="background-color:black">` to not have to add a `<style>` solely for that.

Comment: Quite. Whichever hack is preferable. Personally, I find the `<style/>` tag just makes it much easier to move declarations back and forth from CSS.

Comment: Yeah I agree that they are less obtrusive. One way or another, this hack seems to be the best solution.

Comment: That would be a correct answer, with one addendum: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=311
Being that your body should be clear of margins to make sure the color covers the entire window. Not that it's an issue of the site covered here. Also to help prevent a slow load of your backgrounds you can preload them much earlier with: <style>head{ background: url(/images/bg3.jpg)}</style> before your css file.

Comment: Still a problem in 2017. <html style="background-color:black"> fixes it instantly. But now I need to fade-in the background-image (just for the esthetics).